# Laravel Spark - Adding additional fields to registration form, but when empty no errors are returned

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-spark

I'm building my first app with Laravel 5.2 & Laravel Spark. The front end is built using `Vue.js` I believe and despite adding the following to `register-common-form.blade.php`:

```
<!-- Username -->
<div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': registerForm.errors.has('username')}">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="name" class="form-control" name="username" v-model="registerForm.username" autofocus>

    <span class="help-block" v-show="registerForm.errors.has('username')">
        @{{ registerForm.errors.get('username') }}
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't actually see a way to fully register that extra field so that it is picked up for error handling. I've got it so that the `UserRepository` handles the field and inserts it, but just can't get the front end errors to show properly.

Is anyone able to help with this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally stumbled across it :D

In `Laravel\Spark\Interactions\Auth\CreateUser.php` there is a `$rules` method like so:

```
public function rules($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'vat_id' => 'max:50|vat_id',
            'terms' => 'required|accepted',
        ];
    }
```

All I have done is add my username field, and it works brilliantly!

```
public function rules($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'vat_id' => 'max:50|vat_id',
            'terms' => 'required|accepted',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: when we do `spark:update`, that file would be replaced...am I right?

Comment: @ZaffarSaffee Yes unfortunately, this is based off of experimentation due to lack of documentation in the beginning. Taylor has now added this as a cookbook tutorial on the Spark documentation with the proper implementation

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is just for validation rules you also need to navigate to `spark\src\Repositories\UserRepository.php` and add `'username' => $data['username'],` to the `create()` method like this:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    $user = Spark::user();

    $user->forceFill([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'], // ADDED THIS
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'confirmation_code' => str_random(30),
        'last_read_announcements_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'trial_ends_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(Spark::trialDays()),
    ])->save();

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Would this also not be affected by doing an update to Spark? Very different to what Taylor has put here from what I can see - https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/adding-registration-fields

Comment: I don't see any differences in the link or docs: "Next, we need to customize Spark's new user validation and storage methods to handle our new age field."

Comment: So is this the `booted` method in the SparkServiceProvider? I'm only querying because you mention `spark\src` in your answer which seems like its going to be overwritten with an update